# SVM - dealing with non-symmetric data

Tags: svm, data-transformation

My understanding of SVM is that (a) it is better to transform your target variable such that it is symmetrically distributed, and (b) that it is better to scale all variables to some range e.g. by subtracting mean and dividing by std dev, or by a linear scaling to between [0 .. 1]. This raises a few questions, when you have data that is not symmetrically distributed, which I've not been able to answer.

1. Should I make a transformation (e.g. log) before applying the scaling/normalisation, or afterwards? Although, for the target variable maybe you don't need to scale that at all -- so maybe it's only the next questions that are relevant.
2. Should I also transform the (non-symmetric) input variables as well as the target? I think probably not as we're only trying to minimise the error function in the target - but I have some doubts.
3. If yes to (2), do we use the same transformation as for the every variable? Or do I use a bespoke transformation for each non-symmetric input variable?